# Couldn't get network print to work with SHARP MX-M354U

Tags: networking, printing, printer, network-printer

I have a very strange problem with my network printer (SHARP MX-M354U). The printer is connected to my local network and i can access its configuration web page using it IP address. I am running window 10 and even though windows could not automatically detect the printer when i try to add it, i have added it manually to my printers list (at which point windows successfully connect to the printer and detected and install the necessary drivers for it).

Now when it try to print to it, it silently fails. The printer job dialog doesn't show any errors and it appears it  has successfully sent the print job to the printer. The printer configuration is using RAW print with port 9100, in a desperate attempt I tried to open that port in windows firewall setting with no luck.

I have the same issue when i try to use the printer from Mac OS X Yosemite. In this case, the printer is automatically detected and added to the printers list but could not print to it. No errors or warning as before.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility, especially for the Mac. The Mac will automatically install the PostScript driver. In your printer, PostScript is optional. The standard PDL is PCL6. Does your printer have the PostScript option installed?

The same could also be the case with Windows, but there you have more options. Which driver did you install?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have installed PCL, PS and PPD dirvers. The result is the same with all of them.

Comment: Apparently it was a driver issue. I don't know what went wrong (or right) but installing "Sharp Advanced Printing Language-c Driver [WHQL]" fixed the issue on Windows while all other SHARP PCL 6, PS or PPD drivers failed to work.